# google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError [Python]

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

```
import json
import csv
import google.analytics.data


# Load the JSON key file
with open('key.json', 'r') as f:
    service_account_info = json.load(f)

# Create a service account object
service_account = service_account_info['client_email']

# Create a Google Analytics Reporting API client
client = google.analytics.data.BetaAnalyticsDataClient()


# Set the view ID
view_id = '74466483'

# Set the date range
start_date = '2023-01-01'
end_date = '2023-05-01'

# Define the metrics and dimensions
metrics = ['ga:sessions', 'ga:bounce_rate', 'ga:average_time_on_page', 'ga:entrances', 'ga:pageviews', 'ga:unique_pageviews']
dimensions = ['ga:source', 'ga:page']

# Run the report
report = client.run_report(
    view_id,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    metrics,
    dimensions
)

# Write the report to a CSV file
with open('report.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(report.header)
    for row in report.rows:
        writer.writerow(row)

ERROR:


$ python CompanyName.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel Kamen\Desktop\CompanyNameCode\CompanyName.py", line 14, in <module>
    client = google.analytics.data.BetaAnalyticsDataClient()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\google\analytics\data_v1beta\services\beta_analytics_data\client.py", line 426, in __init__
    self._transport = Transport(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\google\analytics\data_v1beta\services\beta_analytics_data\transports\grpc.py", line 148, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\google\analytics\data_v1beta\services\beta_analytics_data\transports\base.py", line 100, in __init__
    credentials, _ = google.auth.default(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\google\auth\_default.py", line 648, in default
    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_CLOUD_SDK_MISSING_CREDENTIALS)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc for more information.
```

I was given administrator access to my company's google analytics account, so I'm really lost at whats needed to run this. The goal is to export the company data into a csv file to help transition our old data into GA4

I really am lost so I'm not sure what to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because, as [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/analytics-data/latest/v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClient.html) explains, the method `BetaAnalyticsDataClient()` does accept an optional `options` object, that has `credentials` inside.

Whether it isn't provided, it will search for default ones (that in your case aren't instantiated).

To specify them, simply:

```
client = google.analytics.data.BetaAnalyticsDataClient(options={"credentials":{"client_email": service_account, "private_key": "YOUR_KEY"}})
```

Or, for a more readable alternative, create a dict outside and call it.

```
credentials_dict = {
    "options": {
        "client_email": service_account,
        "private_key": "YOUR_KEY"
    }
}
client = google.analytics.data.BetaAnalyticsDataClient(options=credentials_dict)
```

Either, if you have `gcloud` SDK in your computer, you can visit the suggested [link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc?hl=it#how-to) in the error message and setup a default credential!

Hope it actually fixes your problem. I do not have Google Analytics credentials so I cannot test it.

Comment: So since I have service_account_info being creeated through the json file, should remove the service_account = service_acount_info['client_email']? I believe I'd still need to read the json file

Comment: @DanielKamen i see what you did there.. the problem is: you aren't using this `service_account` variable. You just instantiated it. It should be enough to put it into the dictionary i specified

Comment: Fixed it :) because i didn't notice you recalled the `client_email` variable

Comment: Probably this `key.json` contains exactly the properties needed in the `options`. try passing the  `whole service_account_info` to `options`, like so: `client = google.analytics.data.BetaAnalyticsDataClient(options=service_account_info)`

Comment: Got the credential issues resolved, thank you!

Now Im getting these errors which are weird considering I've imported everything needed.
 line 3, in <module>
    import googleanalytics
  File "C:\...\site-packages\googleanalytics\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import auth, commands, utils, account, auth, blueprint, columns, errors, query, segments
  File "C:..\__init__.py", from . import oauth
  File "C:\...\oauth.py",
    from oauth2client import client
  File "C:\\client.py", 
    import urlparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'

Comment: probably, you didn't install the package, you didn't enter the virtual environment or the import is missing.. as i can see quickly browsing the internet, `urlparse` is part of `urllib.parse` since python 3. anyway, if this did the trick, please check it as solution. it's better not to mix errors under one stackoverflow thread

Comment: AH good idea, this was my first post so appreciate the help, and tips for SO practice!

Comment: @DanielKamen personally, i'm glad to help and i wish to be useful.. but people here in stackoverflow can be very strict! your post was well-written enough to not receive a ton of downvotes! :D

Comment: You were more than helpful i appreciate it (its not your job to debug my code)

Comment: I love helping people. I do empathize people like you because skill is something you acquire with time and I was just like you. Thank you for being so kind, have a nice day!